# How to save information that will not be erased during uninstall and restore it back after new version is installed

Tags: react-native

I update my react native app manually and I don't want to lose some information during this process. How can I store some information before update and retrieve them when the new version is uninstalled?

I've tried

- AsyncStorage
- SQLite
- RNFS

Comment: on android uninstalls wipes everything. on iOS, expo's secure store seems to presist through uninstalls. you may have to implement platform specific code to achvie this.

Answer (score 0):

On Android, you can go for different approaches like enabling auto backup or setting fragile data options on your manifest file.

Enabling auto backup will persist SharedPreferences or the other data you are saving to the device. hasFragileUserData flag works different, basically it asks user if they want to keep the applications data when they are trying to uninstall it.

Please see following documentation:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup#EnablingAutoBackup
https://gist.github.com/agnostic-apollo/58def38fdb1c90563454974108ae52df

Comment: I've used RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath. It turns out that if it's a document, then it's not deleted during the uninstall process. Thanks anyways 